# Chrome extension to change HTML tags automatically when loading pages?

Tags: conversion, google-chrome-extensions, html

Is there any Chrome extension that intercepts a page loading and converts specific tags before showing the final page?
For example, if some page contains `<br>` and I want it to be `<p>` before showing it?

Comment: If you are adept at coding in Javascript, you could chavk out the Tampermonkey extension

Answer (score 1):

I can only imagine such a concept with an extension that lets you generally modify a page's CSS/JavaScript. One such extension is called [Custom JavaScript for websites](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija?hl=en). It also lets you use jQuery which makes the task much easier.

Replacing `<br>` with `<p>` doesn't really work though, they are not the same type of element. If you want wider line breaks, replace with `<br><br>`.

StackOverflow has a number of answers on how to replace tags, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093417/using-jquery-to-replace-one-tag-with-another

Also: There are some RegEx replace extensions, which might allow you to do this. You can write RegEx replace in JavaScript too though.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, you would a script such as (untested) :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{$('body').html($('body').html().replace(/<br>\\*/g,"<p></p>"));});
</script>
```

Another tool is [Greasemonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey),
which on Chrome is the
[Tampermonkey extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en).
A sample idea for a script is (untested) :

```
bps = document.getElementsByTagName("bp");
if (bps.length > 0) {
  for (i = 0, j = bps.length; i < j; i++) {
     var p = document.createElement("p");
     p.innerHTML = bps[i].innerHTML
     bps[i].parentNode.replaceChild(p, bps[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I was able to make Tampermonkey work with a simple command, for example, `alert ('test');` (although I could not find this hidden code when trying to view this command within the source code of the page).
But putting your example function up, Tampermonkey gives a lot of syntax errors.
How could I correctly insert your code there?

Comment: Corrected it, and it also saves the text inside `<bp>text</bp>`. Let me know if there are any errors and what they are.

Comment: thanks, but it's working half. I think you haven't tested it, right? First, I needed to add `var` in front of `bps` and `i` to avoid errors. Second, when you write `"bp"` would be `"br"` isn't? But I did a script to change all `h3` tags to `h1` using your script.  But it seems to convert just half of tags. I tried with this page: http://sandbox.sortemaniasudoeste.com.br/resultados/. What could be wrong?

Comment: I did test it, but not thru Greasemonkey (I don't use Chrome). Strange that it didn't work for you. Will try it later.